# YouTube API query cost - single vs multiple video id's

Tags: youtube-data-api

I would like to know if there is any difference in query quota cost when providing single or multiple video id's in a single request?

For example, when querying "youtube.videos.list" you can specify a single or a comma-separated list of video identifiers for the "id" parameter.
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list

If I would like to retrieve snippet and statistics parts of the video, would that always cost me 5 units (1+2+2), no matter if response contains information for one or ten video id's?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No matter the parameters given in your request a [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) request will always cost you a single quota unit.